# Google Conversion tracking Pentaho

Tags: google-analytics, pentaho, google-ads-api, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-ctools

I am into a different situation here, I have been working with **google analytic** in pentaho, to fetch aggregate values on the dashboard, but now the situation is different, company want to see if an order was converted, what were the **keywords** that the customer had used to come to our site to make that **order/transaction** conversion, is it possible to track this condition?

I had seen the **orders/transaction id** in the google analytic view though. And conversions in the analytic dashboard shows how many were converted, not individually.

Can someone guide me to the right path?

Answer (score 0):

I have played with google analytic tool and found out the keywords can be found by selecting:

Conversions > Ecommerce > Sales Performance > NEW SEGMENT[ paid traffic ] > APPLY From Secondary Dimension > Advertising > **Matched Search Query**

**Matched Search Query** ( Gives exact search phrase used by customer )

**Keyword** ( Keywords group that it matched under a campaign )

Many options are available, you can test yourself. :)

But real thing was how to fetch this **report** using the **metrics** and **dimensions** via the **API calls**.

I used query explorer, tried different combinations at:

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

So in my case i needed **transaction id** and **keywords** ,the combinations should be :

**Metrics:**

1. ga:transactions (Transactions)

**Dimensions:**

1. ga:transactionId
2. ga:keyword
3. ga:adGroup
4. ga:adMatchType
5. ga:adMatchedQuery
6. ga:adDestinationUrl
7. ga:sourceMedium

There can be many other options to select from the Metrics and Dimensions, correct combination selection is something to figure out, i used help from:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#mode=web&cats=ecommerce

Hope this helps, if someone wants to share more knowledge, please do :)